# Calculate the Definite Integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, stochastic-integrals

I need to calculate the integral of a function $$f(x)=x^2e^{-x^2}$$ in the range of $a\leq |x|\leq b $.

> **My attempt**: The integral can be divided in two integral according to range    $$I=\int_{-b}^{-a}f(x)dx + \int_a^bf(x)dx $$ As it is clear that $f(x)$ is even function, so $$I=2\int_a^bf(x)dx $$ Now, integral can be divided into $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int_0^bf(x)dx-\int_0^af(x)dx$$Now by using this definition Integral, we can solve the Integral  $$\int_0^ux^2e^{-q^2x^2}=\frac{1}{2q^3}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\Phi(qu)-qu e^{-q^2u^2} \right)$$ where $\Phi$ is CDF of standard normal distribution.

I am not sure whether I am correct or not.

Comment: What is $q$? In general, this integral can be computed via integration by parts.

Comment: Write the integrand as $x.xe^{-x^{2}}$ and then use parts on $u=x, v=xe^{-x^{2}}$

Comment: @ Oles Wohnzimmer: $q$ is a constant.

Comment: I am more curious about limits. Is my attempt of handling with limits is wrong??

Comment: What is $\Phi$?

Comment: If by limits, you mean the integration limits, then yes it is right, but unnecessary, since you can write down antiderivative via integration by parts.

Comment: @5xum $\Phi$ is CDF of standard normal distribution.

Comment: i get this answer with matlab
i hope it can help you
$\int_{a}^{b} x^2\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}=[{\sqrt{\pi}erf(x)\over4}-{xe^{-x^2}\over 2}]_{a}^{b} $

Comment: @Afla.a: I think it is correct half because you miss the mod in range.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts

\begin{equation}
\int x^{2} \mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}} dx = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi} x^{2} \mathrm{erf}(x) - \sqrt{\pi} \int x \, \mathrm{erf}(x) dx
\end{equation}

Integrate by parts again
\begin{align}
\int x \,\mathrm{erf}(x) dx 
&= x^{2} \mathrm{erf}(x) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} x \mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}} 
- \int x \,\mathrm{erf}(x) dx - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int \mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}} dx \\
&= x^{2} \mathrm{erf}(x) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} x \,\mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}} 
- \int x \mathrm{erf}(x) dx - \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{erf}(x) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} x^{2} \mathrm{erf}(x) + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} x \mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}}
- \frac{1}{4} \mathrm{erf}(x)
\end{align}

Thus we have
\begin{equation}
\int x^{2} \mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \mathrm{erf}(x) - \frac{1}{2} x \mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}}
\end{equation}

Comment: You didn't touch my point. I want focus on limits with mod